# "filename.rdata" file Exploring and Converting to CSV

Tags: r, data-visualization, python, dataset

I'm no R-programmer (because of the problem I started learning it), I'm using Python, In a forcasting task I got a dataset [signalList.rdata](http://pdcluster.r-forge.r-project.org/signalList.RData) of a pheomenen called  partial discharge.
I tried some commands to load, open and view, Hardly got a glimps

```
my_data <- get(load('C:/Users/Zack-PC/Desktop/Study/Data Sets/pdCluster/signalList.Rdata'))
```

but, since i lack deep knowledge about R, I wanted to convert it into a csv file, or any type that I can deal with in python.

or, explore it and copy-paste manually.

so, i'm asking for any solution whether using R or Python or any tool to get what's in the .rdata file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you managed to load the data successfully into your working environment?

If so, write.csv is the function you are looking for.

If not,

```
setwd("C:/Users/Zack-PC/Desktop/Study/Data Sets/pdCluster/")
signalList <- load("signalList.Rdata")
write.csv(signalList, "signalList.csv")
```

should do the trick.
If you would like to remove signalList from your working directory,

```
rm(signalList)
```

will accomplish this.

**Note**: changing your working directory isn't necessary, it just makes it easier to read in a comment I feel. You may also specify another path for saving your csv to within the second argument of write.csv.

Comment: It worket, Thanks, but only for two files, 
I think the issue is with structure, and that was the error code:
> write.csv(signalList, "my_signalLit.csv")
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3972, 2287, 723, 824, 2145, 109, 381, 3188, 625, 132, 523, 2329, 478, 3133, 822, 458, 532, 3625, 1398, 1531, 1366, 8674, 564, 227, 455
-----
just to show the data structure
str(signalList)
List of 25
 $ : num [1:3972] 2.2 1.5 5.6 1.56e-16 3.6 ...
 $ : num [1:2287] 2.2 1.5 5.6 1.55e-16 3.5 ...
 $
 $