# Converting RData to CSV file returns incorrect CSV file

Tags: r, csv, rdata

I do not have any expertise on R and I have to convert RData files to CSV to analyze the data. I followed the following links to do this: [Converting Rdata files to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413728/converting-rdata-files-to-csv-error-in-data-frame-arguments-imply-differing-nu) and ["filename.rdata" file Exploring and Converting to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582204/filename-rdata-file-exploring-and-converting-to-csv). The second option seemed to be a simpler as I failed to understand the first one. This is what I have tried till now and the results along with it:

```
>ddata <- load("input_data.RData")
>print(ddata)
[1] "input_data"
> print(ddata[[1]])
[1] "input_data"
> write.csv(ddata,"test.csv")
```

From the first link I learnt that we can see the RData type and when I did `str(ddata)` I found out that it is a List of size 1. Hence, I checked to see if `print(ddata[[1]])` would print anything apart from just "input_data". With the `write.csv` I was able to write it to a csv without any errors but it has just the following 2 lines inside the CSV file:

```
"","x"
"1","input_data"
```

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong and show a way to get all the details in a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `ddata` contains the name of the object(s) that `load()` created. Try typing the command `ls()`. That should give you the names of the objects in your environment. One of them should be `input_data`. That is the object. If it is a data frame (`str(input_data)`), you can create the csv file with

```
write.csv(input_data, "test.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this. It is trying to save the actual CSV now but I got the following error: `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 15, 14`. Can you please help me fix this @dcarlson?

Comment: What does `str(input_data)` show? Perhaps `input_data` is not a data frame.

Comment: It starts with this: `List of 1
 $ topology_4:List of 1
  ..$ sample_size_1:List of 20
  .. ..$ dataset_sampling_1 :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ noise_level_1:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ missing_data_level_1:List of 5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ ground_truth         :List of 3`
It has nested lists.

Comment: This it is not a data.frame which is what `write.csv()` requires. There may be a data frame in the list somewhere. Look for `'data.frame': ### obs. of  # variables:` where ### is the number of rows and # is the number of variables.

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson for clarifying this. I figured that it might be easier for me to save the data in json and get the required data from the corresponding key in the json.